# How to write specific columns of a dataframe to a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm writing a script to reduce a large .xlsx file with headers into a CSV, and then write a new CSV file with only the required columns based on the header names.

```
import pandas
import csv

df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Python27\\Work\\spoofing.csv')

time = df["InviteTime (Oracle)"]
orignum = df["Orig Number"]
origip = df["Orig IP Address"]
destnum = df["Dest Number"]

df.to_csv('output.csv', header=[time,orignum,origip,destnum])
```

The error I'm getting is with that last bit of code, and it says

```
ValueError: Writing 102 cols but got 4 aliases
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something stupid, but I've read over the `to_csv` documentation on the pandas website and I'm still at a loss. I know I'm misusing the to_csv parameters but I can't seem to get my head around the documentation.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The way to select specific columns is this -

```
header = ["InviteTime (Oracle)", "Orig Number", "Orig IP Address", "Dest Number"]
df.to_csv('output.csv', columns = header)
```

Comment: Here is [information from the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv) on the parameters.

Comment: Seems to be a mismatch in column names. You can check your columns with df.columns

Comment: Only if one unreasonably repeats it :)

Comment: Is append feature in df.to_csv?

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Answer (score 3):

```
column_list=["column_name1", "column_name2", "column_name3", "column_name4"]

#filter the dataframe beforehand
ds[column_list].to_csv('output.csv',index=False)

#or use columns arg
ds.to_csv('output.csv', columns = column_list,index=False)
```

I provide `index=False` arg in order to write only column values