# Pandas read_csv() parse_dates does not limit itself to the specied column - how to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I want to read in different CSV files and while doing that, convert the time column to seconds since the epoch. However, the date_parser gets applied to more then the specified column, and my data is butchered.

here is my code and some example data:

```
import pandas as pd


TIME_STG = "Datum (UTC)"
PRICE_STG = "Day Ahead Auktion (DE-LU)"
PRICE_FILE = "booking_algorythm/data/energy-charts_Stromproduktion_und_Börsenstrompreise_in_Deutschland_2021.csv"

def get_data(file, *columns):
    types_dict = {}
    parse_dates_list = []
    for column in columns:
        if column == TIME_STG:
            types_dict.update({column: str})
            parse_dates_list.append(column)
        else:
            types_dict.update({column: float})
    data = pd.read_csv(file,
                       sep=",",
                       usecols=columns,
                       dtype=types_dict,
                       parse_dates=parse_dates_list,
                       date_parser=lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, utc=True)).astype(int) // 10**9
    data_np = data.to_numpy()
    return data_np

def get_price_vector():
    data = get_data(PRICE_FILE, PRICE_STG, TIME_STG)
    return data

def main():
    vector = get_price_vector()
    print(vector)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

example data

```
"Datum (UTC)","Kernenergie","Nicht Erneuerbar","Erneuerbar","Last","Day Ahead Auktion (DE-LU)"
2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,8151.12,35141.305,11491.71,43516.88,48.19
2021-01-01T00:15:00.000Z,8147.209,34875.902,11331.25,42998.01,48.19
2021-01-01T00:30:00.000Z,8154.02,34825.553,11179.375,42494.2,48.19
2021-01-01T00:45:00.000Z,8152.82,34889.11,11072.377,42320.32,48.19
2021-01-01T01:00:00.000Z,8156.53,34922.123,10955.356,41598.39,44.68
2021-01-01T01:15:00.000Z,8161.601,34856.2,10867.771,41214.32,44.68
2021-01-01T01:30:00.000Z,8158.36,35073.1,10789.049,40966.95,44.68
2021-01-01T01:45:00.000Z,8151.3,34972.501,10657.209,40664.63,44.68
2021-01-01T02:00:00.000Z,8145.589,34911.037,10637.605,40502.78,42.92
```

and this is the unexpected output - I had expected the price column to be actual data like 44.68.

`.astype(int) // 10**9` is a fast conversion to seconds since the epoch that I found here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine for me if I convert to Unix time after import, i.e.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvdata = """Datum (UTC),Kernenergie,Nicht Erneuerbar,Erneuerbar,Last,Day Ahead Auktion (DE-LU)
2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,8151.12,35141.305,11491.71,43516.88,48.19
2021-01-01T00:15:00.000Z,8147.209,34875.902,11331.25,42998.01,48.19
2021-01-01T00:30:00.000Z,8154.02,34825.553,11179.375,42494.2,48.19
2021-01-01T00:45:00.000Z,8152.82,34889.11,11072.377,42320.32,48.19
2021-01-01T01:00:00.000Z,8156.53,34922.123,10955.356,41598.39,44.68
2021-01-01T01:15:00.000Z,8161.601,34856.2,10867.771,41214.32,44.68
2021-01-01T01:30:00.000Z,8158.36,35073.1,10789.049,40966.95,44.68
2021-01-01T01:45:00.000Z,8151.3,34972.501,10657.209,40664.63,44.68
2021-01-01T02:00:00.000Z,8145.589,34911.037,10637.605,40502.78,42.92
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvdata), parse_dates=["Datum (UTC)"])
df["Timestamp[s]"] = df["Datum (UTC)"].astype(int) // 10**9

print(df.dtypes)
# Datum (UTC)                  datetime64[ns, UTC]
# Kernenergie                              float64
# Nicht Erneuerbar                         float64
# Erneuerbar                               float64
# Last                                     float64
# Day Ahead Auktion (DE-LU)                float64
# Timestamp[s]                               int64
# dtype: object
```

In general, you might even want to do the conversion to datetime after import, to get more control easier. Using vectorized methods instead of lambdas (= iteration on the Python side, unless covered by special optimizations) is also more efficient in my experience.

- if you want to keep the fractional seconds, you can divide the Unix time nanoseconds with  `/ 10**9`, which results in a float. Besides, `1e9` is a float, so the result would always be a float, not matter if you use integer division `//`. See also [Why does integer division yield a float instead of another integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282945/10197418).
- if you'd like to re-arrange the order of the columns, you can do so as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148429/10197418). Besides, if you want to select only certain columns when creating an output e.g. to csv, you can do so as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22019763/10197418).

Comment: How comes your column displays as type float64, if you cast it to int just before?

Comment: With your stepwise parsing and conversion, I get the problem of the time becoming the last column. How can I retain the order of columns?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei I've added some notes, hope that clarifies.