# numpy savetxt: save a matrix as row

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I'm using numpy `savetxt()` to save the elements of a matrix to file as a single row (I need to print lots of them in order).  This is the method I've found:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9]])

with open('myfile.dat','a') as handle:
    np.savetxt(handle, mat.reshape(1,mat.size), fmt='%+.8e')
handle.close()
```

There are 2 questions:

1) Is `savetxt()` the best option? I need to print 1e5 to 1e7 of these things... and I don't want i/o bottlenecking the actual computation.  I'm guessing reopening the file each iteration is a bad plan, speed-wise.

2) Ideally I would have some context data printed to start each row so my output might look like:

```
(N foo mat):

...
6 -2.309 +1.000 +2.000 ...
7 -4.273 +1.000 +2.000 ...
8 -3.664 +1.000 +2.000 ...
...
```

I could do this using `np.append()`, but then the first number won't print as an INT.  Is this sort of thing doable directly in `savetxt()`?  Or do I need a C-like `fprintf()` anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  My original code for printing as an array only works if you want to print once.  The `mat.reshape()` method doesn't just return the reshaped matrix it alters m`mat` itself.  This means the next time through the loop any `linalg` routines will fail.

To avoid this we need to reshape a `copy()` of `mat`.  I've also added a `tmp` variable for clarity.

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9]]) # initialize mat to see format

handle = open('myfile.dat', 'ab')
for n in range(N):
    # perform linalg calculations on mat ...
    meta = foo # based on current mat

    tmp = np.hstack( ([[n]], [[meta]], (mat.copy()).reshape(1,mat.size)) )
    np.savetxt(handle, tmp, fmt='%+.8e')

handle.close()
```

This gets the context data `n` and `meta` in this case.  I can live with `n` being saved as a `float`.

I did some bench marking to check the i/o cost.  I set N=100,000 for the loop, and average the run time for 6 runs:

- no i/o, just computations: 9.1 sec
- as coded above: 17.2 sec
- open 'myfile.dat' to append each iteration: 30.6 sec

So the i/o doubles the runtime and, as expected, constantly opening and closing a file is a bad plan.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a good [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=mat.astype(np.float))
df.to_csv('myfile.dat', sep=' ', float_format='%+.8e', header=False)
```

By default it'll add the index (`index=True`), though if you wanted different context data you could just add that to your data frame and set `index=False`

```
$ cat myfile.dat 
0 +1.00000000e+00 +2.00000000e+00 +3.00000000e+00
1 +4.00000000e+00 +5.00000000e+00 +6.00000000e+00
2 +7.00000000e+00 +8.00000000e+00 +9.00000000e+00
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `to_csv` can append onto an existing file.  This would mean I have to carry around a potentially huge data frame in RAM and dump it to file at the end.I guess I can experiment with the feasibility of this...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Comment: I see.  For now I'm happy with the `savetxt` solution.  It seems sort or roundabout to copy a matrix into a DataFrame just to print it.