# Python: Export a matrix in csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2D matrix with 13 rows and 13 columns (with headers except for the first column) named `correl` in Python. This `correl` matrix was generated from a `DataFrame` and I wish to populate a matrix `correlation` with multiple `correl`. For example:

```
correlation=[]
correl=df.corr()
correlation=correlation.append(correl) #correlation is not a DataFrame
```

The reason why I use the `correlation=[]` it is because I wish to populate the `correlation` with multiple correlation tables. That is why I use the `append` since this is in a loop.

Now I wish to export this correlation matrix in a csv file. I do:

```
with open("C:\destinationfolder\file.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(correlation)
```

I get this error:

`raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named 0'`

Why?
My guess is that I don't have a header for the first column... is there an easier way to export my correlation table to csv?

Comment: Is `correlation` a pandas DataFrame? Have you tried `correlation.to_csv("C:\destinationfolder\file.csv")`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like [`correlation` is a DataFrame too](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html), so you can simply use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
correlation.to_csv("C:\destinationfolder\file.csv")
```

#### Update to answer if you have a list of DataFrames:

If you have a list of DataFrames which you want to make into a csv, you have two options:

1. concat the list into one larger frame, and use `to_csv`:

   ```
   pd.concat(list_of_dataframes).to_csv(...)
   ```
2. iterate over each DataFrame and use `to_csv` with append (`mode='a'`). Something like:

   ```
   list_of_dataframes[0].to_csv(...)  # write first, using headers..  assumes list isn't empty!
   for df in list_of_dataframes[1:]:
       df.to_csv(..., header=False, mode='a')
   ```

   *see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531025/1240268.*

Comment: I didn't explain myself correctly in my question. See the changes in my question. I know that correlation is a DataFrame but not if I append each dataframe in a loop.

Comment: @CharlesM in that case you can either: concat to make one big DataFrame and use to_csv, or mode='a' (append) whilst using to_csv.