# Re-assemble many csvs using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have an infinitely large hard drive space storing an infinitely large csv, but only 4GB of RAM.

Reading the file into pandas is no problem using:

```
reader = pandas.read_csv('./tools/OCHIN_forgeo.csv', chunksize=10000)
for i,r in enumerate(reader):
    result_df = analyze_chunk(r)
    result_df.to_csv('chunk_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

if now I want to reassemble the chunks into a full result, the following would not work:

```
files = glob.glob('chunk_*.csv')
master_df = pandas.concat(pandas.read_csv(f, index_col=False) for f in files)
master_df.to_csv('master_df_output.csv',index=False)
```

how can I iteratively read the chunks and output them to disk without running out of RAM?

Comment: You can append to an open file, as this question shows


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Comment: awesome, do you know if df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', header=False) will respect differences in columns? say one csv is missing a column

Comment: I don;t know of the top of my head.Come to think about it, you don't have to load the files into Python. You could just `cat` them all together (assuming only the first one has a header)

Comment: good point. hey thanks for your help.  I