# Append a df as a column at the end of an csv file using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, append, export-to-excel

I am appending a DF to an excel sheet. For some reason my DF values are being appended to the last row of the first column in my excel, but I need it to be appended as the last column of my excel (which is column BK). I need to include the header as well but don't need the index.

The code I am using to append one specific column in my DF to my excel file

df = pd.DataFrame({"Specific_Column": ['', 'cell 5', 'cell 6']})

df.to_csv('excelfile.csv',columns=['Specific_Column'], mode='a',index=False)

What I am trying to achieve:

| columnA in excel | columnB in excel | Specific_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 5 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 |

What is happening:

| columnA in excel | columnB in excel |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Specific_Column |  |
| --------------- |  |
| Cell 5 |  |
| Cell 6 |  |

Comment: This post answered my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847258/append-pandas-dataframe-column-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_csv('excelfile.csv',columns=['Excel Column A','Excel Column B','Specific_Column'], mode='a',index=False)
```

I can get the following results according to this code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8c2q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCdZk.png)

Try this

Comment: Hi Rain, i made an update to my ask - column A and column B are columns within my excel and i only have 1 column in my df. I am trying to add it to the end of my data in my excel file.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but I can only think of reading the data first, merging it, and then writing it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847258/append-pandas-dataframe-column-to-csv  Thank you for your help, Rain! I found an answer here