# Q: Pandas dataframe from for loop

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pandas

**EDIT 2, 9/1** See my answer below!

Pretty new at Python and Pandas here. I've got a script here that uses a for loop to query my database using each line in my list. That all works great, but I can't figure out how to build a data frame from the results of that loop. Any and all pointers are welcome!

```
#Remove stuff
print "Cleaning list"
def multiple_replacer(key_values):
  replace_dict = dict(key_values)
  replacement_function = lambda match: replace_dict[match.group(0)]
  pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k, v in key_values]), re.M)
  return lambda string: pattern.sub(replacement_function, string)

multi_line = multiple_replacer(key_values)

print "Querying Database..."
for line in source:
  brand_url = multi_line(line)
  #Run Query with cleaned list
  mysql_query = ("select ub.url as 'URL', b.name as 'Name', b.id as 'ID' from api.brand b join api.url_brand ub on b.id=ub.brand_id where ub.url like '%%%s%%' and b.deleted=0 group by 3;" % brand_url)
  list1 = []
  brands = my_query('prod', mysql_query)

print "Writing CSV..."
#Create DF and CSV
for row in brands:
  list1.append({"URL":row['URL'],"Name":['Name'],"ID":['ID']})
  if brands.shape == (3,0):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = brands, columns=['URL','Name','ID'])
  output = df1.to_csv('ongoing.csv',index=False)
```

**EDIT 8/30**
Here is my edit, attempting to use zyxue's method:

```
#Remove stuff
print "Cleaning list"
def multiple_replacer(key_values):
  replace_dict = dict(key_values)
  replacement_function = lambda match: replace_dict[match.group(0)]
  pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k, v in key_values]), re.M)
  return lambda string: pattern.sub(replacement_function, string)

multi_line = multiple_replacer(key_values)

print "Querying Database..."
for line in source:
  brand_url = multi_line(line)
  #Run Query with cleaned list
  mysql_query = ("select ub.url as 'URL', b.name as 'Name', b.id as 'ID' from api.brand b join api.url_brand ub on b.id=ub.brand_id where ub.url like '%%%s%%' and b.deleted=0 group by 3;" % brand_url)
  brands = my_query('prod', mysql_query)

print "Writing CSV..."
#Create DF and CSV
records = []
for row in brands:
  records.append({"URL":row['URL'],"Name":['Name'],"ID":['ID']})
  if brands.shape == (3,0):
    records.append(dict(zip(brands, ['URL', 'Name', 'ID'])))
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
output = df1.to_csv('ongoing.csv', index=False)
```

but this only returns a blank CSV. I'm sure I'm applying it wrong.

Comment: you're overwriting your dataframe with each iteration of your loop.

Comment: Yes, I figured that after I posted. Not sure on a solution, however. Still very new at this and have only worked with static lists, not a for loop, for something like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Comment: @JohnE, what specifically should I be looking at in that question? The answers there assume my CSV already exist.

Comment: Well, the CSV does exist after you write to it once, right?  You just want to append instead of over-writing.  Specifically, I was looking at the answer with the most votes (it wasn't the accepted answer though) using the `mode='a'` option.  I have not tested it, just thought it looked like a good approach.

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes sense. Tried it, but to no avail. I suppose if I created a CSV file before I did the for loop it would work, although I would need to clear that file every time I used to script, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, and I thought I should post the working script. @zyxue was pretty much right.

```
source = open('urls.txt')
key_values = ("http://",""), ("https://",""), ("www.",""), ("\n","")

#Remove stuff
print "Cleaning list"
def multiple_replacer(key_values):
  replace_dict = dict(key_values)
  replacement_function = lambda match: replace_dict[match.group(0)]
  pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k, v in key_values]), re.M)
  return lambda string: pattern.sub(replacement_function, string)

multi_line = multiple_replacer(key_values)

print "Querying Database..."
records = []
for line in source:
  brand_url = multi_line(line)
  #Run Query with cleaned list
  mysql_query = ("select ub.url as 'URL', b.name as 'Name', b.id as 'ID' from api.brand b join api.url_brand ub on b.id=ub.brand_id where ub.url like '%%%s%%' and b.deleted=0 group by 3;" % brand_url)
  brands = my_query('prod', mysql_query)
  #Append results to dict (records)
  for row in brands:
      records.append({"URL":row['URL'],"Name":row['Name'],"ID":row['ID']})

#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records)

#Create CSV    
output = df.to_csv('ongoing.csv',index=False)
```

Essentially, I needed to layer the second for loop under the first and create the 'records' dictionary *before* the looping began. This causes an append to the dictionary for every line in 'source'. Seems like a pretty simple concept now!

Answer (score 1):

```
records = []
for row in brands:
    # if brands.shape == (3,0):
    #     records.append(dict(zip(brands, ['URL', 'Name', 'ID'])))
    # update bug fix:
    if row.shape == (3,0):
        records.append(dict(zip(row, ['URL', 'Name', 'ID'])))

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
output = df1.to_csv('ongoing.csv', index=False)
# ref:
# >>> pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'a': 1, 'b':2}, {'a': 11, 'b': 22}])
#     a   b
#     0   1   2
#     1  11  22
```

Comment: I attempted to implement this solution and it simply returned an empty set. Perhaps I'm not setting it up properly in my code?

Comment: I updated my question above with what it looks like after applying your code.

Comment: First, put this line `records.append({"URL":row['URL'],"Name":['Name'],"ID":['ID']})` out of the for loop. You shouldn't append the header for every element of brands. Second, please show a couple of examples of brands (e.g. what does `print brands[:2]` looks like?). Also make sure `brands` does have elements of shape (3,0)

Comment: Thanks for working through this with me. here is a sample output when using `print brands`:
`[{'URL': 'http://teespring.com', 'Name': 'Teespring', 'ID': 12345L}]`

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in my code, it should've been `row.shape` and `zip(row, [...])`. I have updated my answer. **However**, if `brands` is a list of dictionaries already, simply try need to `df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(brands)` and you should get the proper `df1` you want, no for loop needed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I'm not sure what the issue is, because from what I can tell, your code **should** work.