# Pandas Appending to CSV check if file has header before appending

Tags: pandas, csv

I am trying to append several pandas dataframes to a csv file but I cannot know ahead of time which dataframe will be appended first as they are each generated on different worker machines. I can append each one to pre-made empty csv file by doing: `df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', header=False)` but then my csv has no header and I just has data.

If I make `header=True` then I have copies of the header every time I append which is redundant since they are all the same. Is there any direct way to overcome this? I suppose I can check the file each time I want to append to see if there is a header but that feels inefficient.

Comment: Can't you make an empty csv file with the universal header and always append data without header to the file?

Comment: Always use `mode='a'` with `header=(not os.path.exists(filename))`?

Comment: @YilunZhang Would I have to do that manually each time?

Comment: @JaminSore That's pretty clever, gonna give it a go.

Comment: Check this old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file/30292938#30292938