# How to concat multiple dataframes to one and output it to a csv file in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a csv file which looks like below

```
,date,location,device,provider,cpu,mem,load,drops,id,latency,gw_latency,upload,download,sap_drops,sap_latency,alert_id
0,2018-02-10 11:52:59.342269+00:00,CFE,10.0.100.1,BWE,6.0,23.0,11.75,0.0,,,,,,,,
1,2018-02-10 11:53:04.006971+00:00,CDW,10.0.100.1,GRE,6.0,23.0,4.58,0.0,,,,,,,,
2,2018-02-09 11:52:59.342269+00:00,,,SSD,,,10.45,,,,,,,,,
3,2018-02-08 09:52:59.342269+00:00,,,BWE,,,12.45,,,,,,,,,
4,2018-02-07 04:52:59.342269+00:00,,,RRW,,,9.45,,,,,,,,,
5,2018-02-06 05:52:59.342269+00:00,,,GRE,,,5.45,,,,,,,,,
6,2018-02-05 07:52:59.342269+00:00,,,SSD,,,13.45,,,,,,,,,
7,2018-02-04 10:52:59.342269+00:00,,,SSD,,,8.15,,,,,,,,,
8,2018-02-03 10:52:59.342269+00:00,,,GRE,,,4.15,,,,,,,,,
9,2018-02-02 06:52:59.342269+00:00,,,RRW,,,13.15,,,,,,,,,
10,2018-02-10 22:35:33.438948+00:00,QQW,10.12.11.1,VCD,4.0,23.0,5.0,0.0,,,,,,,,
11,2018-02-10 22:35:37.905242+00:00,CSW,10.12.11.1,VCD,4.0,23.0,6.08,0.0,,,,,,,,
.......................................................................................
.......................................................................................
```

I load up the csv file like below

```
df = pd.read_csv("metrics_copy.csv", parse_dates=["date"])   
df['device'] = df['device'].astype(str)
unique_devices = (np.unique(df[['device']].values))
unique_provider = np.unique(df[['provider']].values)
```

I want to get a csv file which contains only certain columns for a certain combination.

```
for i in unique_devices:
    for j in ["cpu", "mem"]:
        df2 = df[(df['device'] == i)]
        df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
        print(df2[j])
```

As you can see, for every unique combination of device and metric, I will get a a time series data.I am able to get a bunch of values for `df2[j]` for a given device.I want to output these values to a csv file for all combinations as long as the loop continues..I am aware of a concept called pd.concat which can be used like below

```
df_final = pd.concat([df, df2, df3.....])
```

But for that I need to generate the dataframes for all possible combinations and then finally concat them to become one dataframe.So I want the end result csv file to look something like below for `cpu`

```
date cpu
...  ...
...  ...
```

And another csv file for `mem` which looks something like below

```
date mem
...  ...
...  ...
```

But I am not sure how do I achieve this.Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file shows how to use the pandas.to_csv() function in append 'a' mode. Which would append as your loop goes to your two different files.

Comment: @Lina great!but I need to solve the challenge of getting the data for every loop and storing it until the inner loop breaks.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but couldn't you use df2['mem'].to_csv('mem.csv', mode='a', header=False) and df2['cpu'].to_csv('cpu.csv', mode='a', header=False)  in the inner loop and once it breaks, you are left with the final file with all the dataframes that were generated?

Comment: @Lina great! This is what I wanted!I misunderstood your earlier response.You may post this as an answer and I wil accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the following using df.to_csv() in append mode: [How to add pandas data to an existing csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file)

```
for i in unique_devices:
    for j in ["cpu", "mem"]:
        df2 = df[(df['device'] == i)]
        df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
            df2[['date',j]].to_csv('{}.csv'.format(j), mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Alternatively you can have an if statement to check if the file exists so the first time it's made, the header will be used, and thereafter it is ignored:

```
for i in unique_devices:
    for j in ["cpu", "mem"]:
        df2 = df[(df['device'] == i)]
        df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
        import os
        if not os.path.isfile('{}.csv'.format(j)):
            df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(j), mode='a', index=False)
        else:
            df2[['date',j]].to_csv('{}.csv'.format(j), mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```