# Saving pandas datasets to csvs without overwriting existing files

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

Is there a way of using `to_csv("xxx.csv")` in Python without overwriting an existing file?

In other words, if I ran `to_csv("xxx.csv")` twice in succession, I would like to have 2 output files in my folder, not one.

Comment: Use `mode='a+'`

Comment: can't you tell it to use the append method?

Comment: @MRHarv , you need to provide the details what do you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add pandas data to an existing csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file)

Comment: @d_kennetz, thats is Exactly duplicate .

Comment: `mode='a+' ` does not solve this.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I do not want to add data to an existing file, I want a separate file created that does not overwrite the existing one.

Comment: You cannot have 2 files by the same name in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have two different files, you need to give them two different names. There is no way around this, and it makes sense and is usually enforced at the OS level.

You can try it yourself by trying to create two files with the same name via the terminal or a GUI.

Comment: I was hoping the second time I ran `to_csv("xxx.csv")` , the file gets named as xxx(1).csv instead of overwriting, but I guess it is just not possible. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible, you have to tell python to do that though. It does not do it inherently because that is generally not desired behavior.

Comment: Where would I look, to be able to tell python to do this?

Comment: Change the file path like `/data/location_1/myfile.csv` and next time  `/data/location_2/myfile.csv` then you have  same file name!

Comment: There is no way to "tell" python other than giving it a new name string everytime it is called. You'd also need to keep track of the number of times it's been called to append the number to the end

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for the benefit of other users. I am running a monthly process and so the only way to not overwrite files is to use `.format()` within the file name.

e.g. `.to_csv("xxx{}.csv".format(a), index=False)`, where `a` increases by 1 each month, so there is no overwriting involved.

Comment: So you are appending a number`(1,2,3)` at the end of `xxx`. So, this is NOT HAVING the same file name anymore.

Comment: It is the same file, with a different name.