# How to write a pandas.DataFrame to csv file with custom header?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

I want to write `df` to a csv file but not using the columns `['a', 'b']`. The first line is my custom string and the rest are the content of `df.values`. For example:

```
numrows numcols note
1 2
3 4
```

Can I do this with pandas or I have to manually loop through the content and write to file?

Comment: you can rename columns in dataframe before you save it.

Comment: why don't check documentation for [dataframe.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). There is option `header` - maybe it renames headers in file.

Comment: @furas I want to write a custom string, it's not the same number of columns with the data content. See my example above.

Comment: check `header`  again - you can use different names than in columns.

Comment: @furas header can change value, but the number of columns must not change.

Comment: if you add empty column then you will have three columns with three headers - and you can normally save it . But in file you will see three headers with two columns - last empty column will be invisible for you.

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer is wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can first create a csv file with the custom text in the first line, and then *append* the dataframe to it.

```
with open('file.csv', 'a') as file:
    file.write('Custom String\n')
    df.to_csv(file, header=False, index=False)
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file) post.

So, in your case, just use this

```py
with open('file.csv', 'a') as file:
    file.write('numrows numcols note\n')
    df.to_csv(file, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: This is a principled solution, and works well when setting the write-mode correctly. I'm not sure which answer to accept. Will accept by the vote count later.

Comment: @divyanshu-srivastava Worked well for me Div. Too bad we can't bold the title or other things at the same time.

Comment: Wait. This is wrong. You can run the code twice to see why : 'file.csv' will have two headers and two contents. "You can first create a csv file with the custom text in the first line, and then append the dataframe to it. " The problem is that if the file already exists, it appends the custom text to the existing content.

Answer (score 8):

Improving over @Divyanshu Srivastava [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56166776/7041244):

Not that it matters a lot, but no need for keeping open files:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
     f.write('Custom String\n')

df.to_csv(file_path, header=False, mode="a")
```

Comment: Its the same, just that in this case the file is opened twice.

Comment: Yes, only when you supply a file object instead of a path, you disable universal newlines, which in most cases won't budge anyone but still :)

Comment: The problem with the accepted answer is that it appends the header to whatever 'file.csv' was containing before. It doesn't just append the content to the header.

Answer (score 2):

First write custom string and then all data without columns in append mode:

```
file = 'file.csv'
pd.DataFrame(columns=['numrows numcols note']).to_csv(file, index=False)
df.to_csv(file, header=None, index=False, mode='a')
```

Comment: There is no need to create a Dataframe for the first custom string.

Comment: Creating an entire dataframe just for a header is wasteful

Comment: I like this answer because it's all in pandas, thus it shows the strength and limits of pandas.

Comment: @THN The question never stated that an all-panda answer is expected.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava - First, it is still for OP, what answer is accepted :) So downvoting is possible, but not sure if good way for persuade another people about your solution is best.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava That's right, any good solution is appreciated.

Comment: This is a slower approach.