# Writing pandas dataframe appended text on the top

Tags: pandas

I have the pandas data frame. I want to write it in a text file and add text on the top of the frame.

e.g (this is the data.

```
0   <+000.0 +000.0  +050.0  +000.8>
1   <+000.0 +000.0  +049.1  +000.6>
2   <+000.0 +000.0  +047.6  +000.6>
3   <+000.0 +000.0  +046.5  +000.5>
4   <+000.0 +000.0  +045.3  +000.6>
```

I want to write it to the file (file.txt) but the following text should be in the file:

```
#my meas.
#done by me.
#pdd

0   <+000.0 +000.0  +050.0  +000.8>
1   <+000.0 +000.0  +049.1  +000.6>
2   <+000.0 +000.0  +047.6  +000.6>
3   <+000.0 +000.0  +046.5  +000.5>
4   <+000.0 +000.0  +045.3  +000.6>
```

as I'm new to this, I managed only to create the data frame and write it to a csv file.

Please help.

Comment: this is possible but probably not worth your time/effort to do.  Why not just add a separate file with metadata, or do it by hand?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166681/how-to-write-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file-with-custom-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dataframe of the strings you want at the top and then append your main dataframe. Make sure the column names are the same before appending, so that it lines up (`0` in my example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: '<+000.0 +000.0  +050.0  +000.8>',
  1: '<+000.0 +000.0  +049.1  +000.6>',
  2: '<+000.0 +000.0  +047.6  +000.6>',
  3: '<+000.0 +000.0  +046.5  +000.5>',
  4: '<+000.0 +000.0  +045.3  +000.6>'}})
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['#my meas.', '#done by me.', '#pdd', '']}).append(df)
df.to_csv(header=False, index=False)
df
Out[1]: 
                                 0
0                        #my meas.
1                     #done by me.
2                             #pdd
3
0  <+000.0 +000.0  +050.0  +000.8>
1  <+000.0 +000.0  +049.1  +000.6>
2  <+000.0 +000.0  +047.6  +000.6>
3  <+000.0 +000.0  +046.5  +000.5>
4  <+000.0 +000.0  +045.3  +000.6>
```