# Python : Writing to csv with headers

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a csv file with header in python and then append data to it by each run.But after each run the header as well as export_data is appended to the file. How can I prevent header to write each time?

```
ColA  ColB
item1 item2
item3 item4
```

Here is my code in python:

```
list1 = ['item1','item3']
list2 = ['item2','item4']
d = [list1,list2]
export_data = it.zip_longest(*d, fillvalue = '')
with open('D:/csv/csvfile.csv', 'a', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(("colA", "colB",))
    wr.writerows(export_data)
```

Comment: Check if 'D:/csv/csvfile.csv' exist. If the answer is no - add the headers, else - dont add them

Comment: you can do that with Pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Comment: @balderman You're right. Thanks!it worked.

Comment: @h.m.gh Glad to help. Feel free to vote up for the comment.