# pandas dataframe to_csv writes blank line after each line

Tags: python, pandas

When I write a data frame to a csv if I use the "with open", I get a blank line after each line in the csv file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (4, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

If I simply do:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', header=False)
```

There is no blank line!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second option is the correct way to use `.to_csv()` with pandas.

Comment: If I use with open, I can check if the file exists or not and If not write the header. If yes, I don't write it. and all this in the same line without a lot of hassle!

Comment: `\r\n` default vs `\n`

Comment: change header=None ?

Comment: Refer to this post  :  `How to add pandas data to an existing csv file?`  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Comment: I'm confused. How either of the options could produce the blank line after **each** line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, the newline of :

```
with open('test.csv', 'a') as f
```

is `\r\n`

The newline in `to_csv()` is `\n`.

You can try with :

```
with open('test.csv', 'a', newline = '\n') as f
```

Comment: If I open the file to write, It doesn't append. It just rewrites

Comment: The `a` parameter for appending instead `w` for writing. Apologize.