# Showing two différents errors with the same code that I used to scrape other pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used a code to scrape two pages from tripadvisor, and it worked very well. But  now, it shows me two differents errors :

```js
with open("iletaitunsquare1.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(["inf_rest_name", "rest_eclf", "name_client", "date_rev_cli", "opinion_cl"])

    with requests. Session() as s:
        for offset in range (270,1230,10):
            url = f'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d6575305-Reviews-or{offset}-Il_Etait_Un_Square-Paris_Ile_de_France.html'
            r = s.get(url)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            reviews = soup.select('.reviewSelector')
            ids = [review.get('data.reviewid') for review in reviews]
            r = s.post(
                    'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS_RESP&metaReferer=',
                    data = {'reviews': ','.join(ids), 'contextChoice': 'DETAIL'},
                    headers = {'Referer': r.url}
                    )

            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            if not offset:
                inf_rest_name = soup.select_one('.heading').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                rest_eclf = soup.select_one('.header_links a').text.strip()

            for review in soup.select('.reviewSelector'):
                name_client = review.select_one('.info_text > div:first-child').text.strip()
                date_rev_cl = review.select_one('.ratingDate')['title'].strip()
                titre_rev_cl = review.select_one('.noQuotes').text.strip()
                opinion_cl = review.select_one('.partial_entry').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                row = [f"{inf_rest_name}", f"{rest_eclf}", f"{name_client}", f"{date_rev_cl}", f"{titre_rev_cl}", f"{opinion_cl}"]
                w.writerow(row)
```

Error on excecution:

> "data = {'reviews': ','.join(ids), 'contextChoice': 'DETAIL'}
>   TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found"

and after I decided to change just values in line 6(pages of site) and 7 (Url):

```js
with open("boutary.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(["inf_rest_name", "rest_eclf", "name_client", "date_rev_cl", "titre_rev_cl", "opinion_cl"])

    with requests.Session() as s:
        for offset in range(40, 290, 10):
            url = f'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d9783452-Reviews-or{offset}-Boutary-Paris_Ile_de_France.html'
            r = s.get(url)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            reviews = soup.select('.reviewSelector')
            ids = [review.get('data-reviewid') for review in reviews]
            r = s.post(
                'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS_RESP&metaReferer=',
                data = {'reviews': ','.join(ids), 'contextChoice': 'DETAIL'},
                headers = {'referer': r.url}
                )

            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

            if not offset:
                    inf_rest_name = soup.select_one('.heading').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                    rest_eclf = soup.select_one('.header_links a').text.strip()

            for review in soup.select('.reviewSelector'):
                name_client = review.select_one('.info_text > div:first-child').text.strip()
                date_rev_cl = review.select_one('.ratingDate')['title'].strip()
                titre_rev_cl = review.select_one('.noQuotes').text.strip()
                opinion_cl = review.select_one('.partial_entry').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                row = [f"{inf_rest_name}", f"{rest_eclf}", f"{name_client}", f"{date_rev_cl}" , f"{titre_rev_cl}", f"{opinion_cl}"]
                w.writerow(row)
```

and it shows me

> "row = [f"{inf_rest_name}", f"{rest_eclf}", f"{name_client}",
>   f"{date_rev_cl}" , f"{titre_rev_cl}", f"{opinion_cl}"]
>
> NameError: name 'inf_rest_name' is not defined"

These errors are strange because, before, I used the same code with other URL and it worked perfectly. 
Can you tell me please what is happening? How can I run it proprerly? I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the original code, not posted here, it was relying on Truthy/Falsy value of offset 0 which in your prior question was the first offset.

For example, with:

```
for offset in range(0, 10, 10):
    if not offset:
```

The first value 0 is a Falsy versus numbers > 0 (in this scenario) which will be seen as Truthy. If not True i.e. False  i.e. if 0 offset then set the value of  `inf_rest_name`. This ensures its value it only set on the first loop rather than each time. Its value doesn't change so no need to read again.

With the following all values are Truthies and so  `inf_rest_name` never gets set.

```
for offset in range(40, 290, 10):
    if not offset:
```

You could change to:

```
if offset == firstvalue:
```

e.g.

```
if offset == 40:
    inf_rest_name = soup.select_one('.heading').text.replace("\n","").strip()
    rest_eclf = soup.select_one('.header_links a').text.strip()
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) for more info.

Those lines also need to work with first soup not later soup (as that is only reviews)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
        for offset in range(40, 290, 10):
            url = f'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d9783452-Reviews-or{offset}-Boutary-Paris_Ile_de_France.html'
            r = s.get(url)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            if offset == 40:
                inf_rest_name = soup.select_one('.heading').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                rest_eclf = soup.select_one('.header_links a').text.strip()
            reviews = soup.select('.reviewSelector')
            ids = [review.get('data-reviewid') for review in reviews]
            r = s.post(
                'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS_RESP&metaReferer=',
                data = {'reviews': ','.join(ids), 'contextChoice': 'DETAIL'},
                headers = {'referer': r.url}
                )

            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

            for review in soup.select('.reviewSelector'):
                name_client = review.select_one('.info_text > div:first-child').text.strip()
                date_rev_cl = review.select_one('.ratingDate')['title'].strip()
                titre_rev_cl = review.select_one('.noQuotes').text.strip()
                opinion_cl = review.select_one('.partial_entry').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                row = [f"{inf_rest_name}", f"{rest_eclf}", f"{name_client}", f"{date_rev_cl}" , f"{titre_rev_cl}", f"{opinion_cl}"]
```

---

For your first code block you are using an invalid attribute. It should be

```
ids = [review.get('data-reviewid') for review in reviews]
```

Note I have added an is None test to handle not found. This should be added to top version as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests. Session() as s:
        for offset in range (270, 1230, 10):
            url = f'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d6575305-Reviews-or{offset}-Il_Etait_Un_Square-Paris_Ile_de_France.html'
            r = s.get(url)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            if offset == 270:
                inf_rest_name = soup.select_one('.heading').text.replace("\n","").strip()
                rest_eclf = soup.select_one('.header_links a').text.strip()
            reviews = soup.select('.reviewSelector')
            ids = [review.get('data-reviewid') for review in reviews]
            r = s.post(
                    'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS_RESP&metaReferer=',
                    data = {'reviews': ','.join(ids), 'contextChoice': 'DETAIL'},
                    headers = {'Referer': r.url}
                    )

            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

            for review in soup.select('.reviewSelector'):
                name_client= review.select_one('.info_text > div:first-child')
                if name_client is None:
                    name_client = 'N/A'
                else:
                    name_client = name_client.text.strip()

                date_rev_cl = review.select_one('.ratingDate')
                if date_rev_cl is None:
                    date_rev_cl = 'N/A'
                else:
                    date_rev_cl  = date_rev_cl['title'].strip()

                titre_rev_cl = review.select_one('.noQuotes')
                if titre_rev_cl is None:
                    titre_rev_cl = 'N/A'
                else:
                    titre_rev_cl = titre_rev_cl.text.strip()

                opinion_cl = review.select_one('.partial_entry')
                if opinion_cl is None:
                     opinion_cl = 'N/A'
                else:
                     opinion_cl =  opinion_cl.text.replace("\n","").strip()

                row = [f"{inf_rest_name}", f"{rest_eclf}", f"{name_client}", f"{date_rev_cl}", f"{titre_rev_cl}", f"{opinion_cl}"]
                print(row)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198527/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-showing-two-differents-errors-with-the-same-code-t).