# drop duplicate data and append the rest in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
import os
from os import path
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sys



while True:
    if path.exists('stockdata.csv') == True:
        data1 = pd.read_csv('stockdata.csv')
        ts = TimeSeries(key='1ORS1XLM1YK1GK9Y', output_format='pandas')
        data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol = 'spy', interval='1min', outputsize='full')
        data = data.rename(columns={'1. open':'Open','2. high': 'High','3. low': 'Low', '4. close':'Close', '5. volume': 'Volume'})
        data1 = data1.append(data)
        data1.to_csv('stockdata.csv', sep= ' ')
        break
    else:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Open','High','Low', 'Close','Volume'])
        data1.to_csv('stockdata.csv', sep= ' ')
```

What i am trying to do is to check if file `stockdata.csv` is in in the current directory. If it is not found then create the file.

If the file is found then download spy ticker data in `data` and append that data to `data1` and save it in csv file.

This is suppose to run for 24/7 and i will include a 12 hours sleep timer so every 12 hours it would update the data.

- I want the dataframe to drop duplicate data and append only new data.

Comment: You might need to include the ".csv" extension in the read_csv and to_csv calls. Does this give you a file called "stockdata" and one called "stockdata.csv"?

Comment: it should not matter because files are exported anyway with to_csv

Comment: If you look in the working directory do you have a file "stockdata.csv" or is it just "stockdata"?

Comment: As a side note, can I suggest a refactor to your code?  First, in Python we generally do not use `== True`.  Change it to `if path.exists('stockdata.csv'):`, instead.  Second, if you change it to `if not path.exists('stockdata.csv'):` and move the `else` part up, you can de-indent the rest.  It seems to me that the logic would be the same (though I'm guessing you're not showing all of it).  By the way, that `break` within the `while True` looks weird.  Is there a more external loop outside of it?

Comment: Please also refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to create an empty file if it does not exist and then keep adding all new data. What I suggest is to read new data and filter so that it only contain new rows. Then you can save the dataframe with append mode ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file)).

```
from os import path

import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries


while True:
    if path.exists("stockdata.csv"):

        # Get new data
        ts = TimeSeries(key="1ORS1XLM1YK1GK9Y", output_format="pandas")
        data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol="spy", interval="1min", outputsize="full")
        data = data.rename(
            columns={
                "1. open": "Open",
                "2. high": "High",
                "3. low": "Low",
                "4. close": "Close",
                "5. volume": "Volume",
            }
        )

        # Filter only new rows
        data1 = pd.read_csv("stockdata.csv")
        data = data[~data.index.isin(data1.index)]

        # Append new rows (add new rows to the existing ones)
        data.to_csv("stockdata.csv", sep=" ", mode='a')

    else:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"])
        data1.to_csv("stockdata.csv", sep=" ")
```

I have also cleaned unused imports to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Will [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) do what you need?

```
data1 = data1.drop_duplicates()
```