# How to add more dataframe to a .txt file in python

Tags: python

How can i add more dataframe to a .txt.

```
content.to_csv('file.txt', index=None)
```

DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Jack','Fred']})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add pandas data to an existing csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file)

Comment: can you please be more clear on your question

Comment: @Hari i created a .txt file using pandas, but i want to add more content. For example the .txt file contains name of student, so i want to create another dataframe (containing names of more student) and add to the previous .txt file, just like how dataframes can be added to .csv