# Read and export in CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv

i have a csv file with data separated by " ; ".
There is no problem reading the file but i want to export the data that was in the first csv no ANOTHER csv and add 1 new column to the new csv file.

```
import csv

with open('1.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('agg.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput,lineterminator=';')

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('Movimiento')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(row[0])
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

[image: output csv] why this happend?

Comment: Try using the below link, this is some what similar to your query.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file)

Comment: i can't use librarys :(

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a csv writer object, and use that object to write in it the required csv file. If you can tell me a little more about the column proble, I will be able to help better with that.

```
csvwriter = csv.writer("1.csv", delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use `pandas` library

try the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('<file_name>', sep =';')
#add new column
data['new_column_name']=[list_of_values]
data.to_csv('<to_filename>', index=False)
```

Comment: Okay, let me check the other way around then

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('1.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('agg.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, delimiter=',')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput,lineterminator=';')

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('Movimiento')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(row[0])
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data has `;` as separator, so you probably want to specify that instead of `lineterminator`:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
reader = csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter=';')
```