# How to save real-time predicted results into a csv file?

Tags: python

I am working on an audio classifier project and currently when I run the predictor in realtime, it captures the a small segments of audio then starts the prediction process then spills out the results through the terminal like this:

```
[INFO] 2020-08-07 14:49:20,695: Predictions: Dog: 1.00
[INFO] 2020-08-07 14:49:20,698: Stop processing.
[INFO] 2020-08-07 14:49:21,707: Start processing.
[INFO] 2020-08-07 14:49:21,847: Predictions: Cat: 0.98
[INFO] 2020-08-07 14:49:21,849: Stop processing.
```

So, what I want is to have these results saved into a CSV file.

**What I did so far:**

Here is my script:

def _process_loop(self):

```
with WavProcessor() as proc:
    self._ask_data.set()
    while True:
        if self._process_buf is None:

            time.sleep(self._processor_sleep_time)                                          #Waiting for data to process
            continue

        logger.info('Start processing.')
        predictions = proc.get_predictions(

            self._sample_rate, self._process_buf)
        logger.info(

            'Predictions: {}'.format(format_predictions(predictions))
        )

        prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['Predicted Class', 'Accuracy']).to_csv('predictions.csv')


        logger.info('Stop processing.')
        self._process_buf = None
        self._ask_data.set()
```

I added this line to my code `(prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['Predicted Class', 'Accuracy']).to_csv('predictions.csv'))` as you can it in the above code, and started getting something here. The thing that I got was only one result saved inside the csv file. Specifically, it saves only the last detected result.

```
Predicted Class          Accuracy
Cat                      0.98
```

So, my current problem is how to save all predicted results inside my CSV file.

I appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Checkout the first answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rewriting the file on each iteration.
You can specify the write `mode` of the pandas `to_csv` function. You can append to an existing file if you set it to `a`.

Something like this:

`pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['Predicted Class', 'Accuracy']).to_csv('predictions.csv', mode='a', header=False)`

Some nice references:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/python-file-modes-open-write-append-r-r-w-w-x-etc/

Comment: Thank you sooo much for helping me out. That definitely solved it. Also, thanks for the references.

Comment: So, I was trying since yesterday to get  the Date and Time info as shown above written next to the predicted results but couldn't make. I tried to follow through the references you provided, thankfully, and used the .at_time but that didn't get me anywhere. Do you think that is possible to do? Since the original passed data had 2 columns only, and the date and time info are generated somehow.. not sure how!

Comment: You mean like add a column to your dataframe with `datetime.now()` ?  Like this: https://www.jquery-az.com/python-datetime-now/

Comment: actually, it is already showing the time and date with the results as you can see in my above shell results ([INFO] 2020-08-07 14:49:20,695: Predictions: Dog: 1.0)... but when I try to add the date & time to a separate column it gives me an error saying: ValueError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns