# Append data frame to an existing csv files with different number of columns

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, open-with, csv-write-stream

How can i append data frame to an existing csv files in python? I am using the following code but this does not check if  the columns are matching or not.

```
new_dataframe.to_csv("my_file.csv")
```

How can i open a csv file and append a data frame to it by matching the columns and once done, close it. The reason I want to do this is because not all the time the data frame can have as same number of column as in the csv file. So, first check the columns and if they are matching then append it, if not then leave it null.

Please any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look into? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975690/5916727

Comment: yes i did and it is not matching the name of columns, it is miss placing columns in csv.