# Save output in CSV without losing previous data on that CSV in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, dataset, output

I'm doing sentiment analysis of Tweeter data. For this work, I've made some datasets in CSV format where different month in different dataset. When I do the preprocessing of every dataset individually, I want to save all dataset in 1 single CSV file. but when I write the below's code by using pandas dataframe:

```
df.to_csv('dataset.csv', index=False)
```

It removes previous data (Rows) of that dataset. Is there any way that I can keep the previous data too on that file? So that I can merge all data together. Thank you..........

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want from your question, so this is just a guess, but something like this might be what you're looking for. if you keep assigning dataframes to `df`, then new data will overwrite the old data. Try reassigning them to differently named dataframes like `df1` and `df21. Then you can merge them.

```
# vertically merge the multiple dataframes and reassign to new variable
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
# save the dataframe 
df.to_csv('my_dataset.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the open("file") method with the parameter 'a':
open("file", 'a').
The 'a' means "append" so you will add lines at the end of your file.
You can use the same parameter for the pandas.dataFrame.to_csv() method.
e.g:

```
import pandas as pd

# code where you get data and return df

pd.df.to_csv("file", mode='a')
```

@thehand0: Your code works, but it's inefficient, so it will take longer for your script to run.