# Attempting to export parsed data to CSV file with Python and I can't figure out how to export more than one row

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I'm fairly new to beautiful soup/Python/Web Scraping and I have been able to scrape data from a site, but I am only able to export the very first row to a csv file ( I want to export all scraped data into the file.)

I am stumped on how to make this code export ALL scraped data into multiple individual rows:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.infoplease.com/primary-sources/government/presidential-speeches/state-union-addresses")
data = r.content  # Content of response
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")


for span in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "article"}):
    for link in span.select("a"):
           
        name_and_date = link.text.split('(')
        name = name_and_date[0].strip()
        date = name_and_date[1].replace(')','').strip()
        
        base_url = "https://www.infoplease.com"
        links = link['href']
        links = urljoin(base_url, links)
        
        
    
    pres_data = {'Name': [name],
                'Date': [date],
                'Link': [links]
                }
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(pres_data, columns= ['Name', 'Date', 'Link'])

    df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\ThinkPad\Documents\data_file.csv', index = False, header=True)

    print (df)
```

Any ideas here? I believe I need to loop it through the data parsing and grab each set and push it in.
Am I going about this the right way?

Thanks for any insight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add pandas data to an existing csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is currently set up, it looks like you are not adding each link as a new entry and instead it is only adding the last link. If you initialize a list and add a dictionary like you have it set up for each iteration of the "links" for loop, you will add each row and not just the last one.

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

r = requests.get("https://www.infoplease.com/primary-sources/government/presidential-speeches/state-union-addresses")
data = r.content  # Content of response
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

pres_data = []
for span in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "article"}):
    for link in span.select("a"):
        
        name_and_date = link.text.split('(')
        name = name_and_date[0].strip()
        date = name_and_date[1].replace(')','').strip()
        
        base_url = "https://www.infoplease.com"
        links = link['href']
        links = urljoin(base_url, links)
        
        this_data = {'Name': name,
                    'Date': date,
                    'Link': links
                    }
        pres_data.append(this_data)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(pres_data, columns= ['Name', 'Date', 'Link'])

df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\ThinkPad\Documents\data_file.csv', index = False, header=True)

print (df)
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks so much. I was just reading about the append action. Really appreciate this

Comment: Awesome, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Pandas` here since you are not willing to apply any kind of `Data` operation there!

Usually try to limit yourself on the builtin libraries in case if the task is shorter.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    target = [([x.a['href']] + x.a.text[:-1].split(' ('))
              for x in soup.select('span.article')]
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Url', 'Name', 'Date'])
        writer.writerows(target)


main('https://www.infoplease.com/primary-sources/government/presidential-speeches/state-union-addresses')
```

Sample of output:

[image]