# Suppress descriptive output when printing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, output-formatting

Say I have dataframe, `c`:

```
a=np.random.random((6,2))
c=pd.DataFrame(a)
c.columns=['A','B']
```

printing row 0 values:

```
print c.loc[(0),:]
```

results in:

```
A    0.220170
B    0.261467
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I would like to suppress the `Name: 0, dtype: float64` line so that I just get:

```
A    0.220170
B    0.261467
```

Does anyone know how?

(n.b. I am appending this to a text file)

Comment: How are you appending this to a text file? Eg when using `to_csv` this will not appear in the text output, it is only in the console display.

Comment: The normal console answer would probably be `df.to_string()`, but if you are appending it to a text file you should definitely use `to_csv` (with `delimiter` set to some spaces).

Comment: I am using `f = open('myfile.txt', 'w')` and  `f.write(str(c) + '\n\n')`. I'll give `to_csv` a go, thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong bu it seems that you can't append with `to_csv`

Comment: You can just pass arg `mode='a'`

Answer (score 5):

You can tweak the `__unicode__` method for a Series:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([1, 2])

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64

In [13]: pd.Series.__unicode__ = pd.Series.to_string

In [14]: s  # same with print
Out[14]:
0    1
1    2
```

*To append to a csv use append mode (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134942/pandas-dataframe-output-end-of-csv) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file) question).*