# Remove excess info from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame that contains 6 columns. When I want to print the info out of one cell, I use the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(Path_files_data)
info_rol = df.loc[df.Rank == Ranknumber]
print(info_rol['Art_Nr'])
```

Here Rank is the column that gives the rank of every item and Ranknumber is the Rank of the item i try to look up. How what i get back looks like this:

```
0    10399
Name: Art_Nr, dtype: object
```

Here 0 is the rank and 10399 is Art_Nr. How do I get it to work that it only printsout the Art_Nr. and leaves al the crap like dtype: object.

PS. I tried strip but that didnt work for me.

Comment: Sure, this is very easy. Just subclass `pd.Series` and modify its `__repr__` method.

Comment: Actually, I'm intrigued by what you mean by "crap". What exactly do you want left out? Only the `dtype`? Or do you just want to print the numerical value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress descriptive output when printing pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295451/suppress-descriptive-output-when-printing-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @djk47463 That's a very interesting duplicate. What about the col name though?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, OP is just calling a series from the dataframe `info_rol['Art_Nr']`, which doesn't print a column header. That is printed as the `Name:` of the series at the bottom, which isnt shown when using the code from the dupe

Comment: @djk47463 yeah, so OP wants the column name I think... not sure the dupe is 100% applicable here. Well, worst case, they can just append it to `to_string` :D

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I not sure he does want the column header, he wants the "crap" at the bottom of a series print removed. But if so wouldnt OP just be asking how to print as a dataframe instead of a series? `print(info_rol[['Art_Nr']])`

Comment: @djk47463 Possibly... I'd put that into an answer, add an example with some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need select first value of Series by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for scalar:

```
print(info_rol['Art_Nr'].iat[0])
```

---

```
print(info_rol['Art_Nr'].iloc[0])
```

If `string` or numeric output:

```
print(info_rol['Art_Nr'].values[0])
```

But after filtering is possible you get multiple values, then second, third.. values are lost.

So converting to list is more general solution:

```
print(info_rol['Art_Nr'].tolist())
```