# Unable to append dataframes to a csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 dataframes with dimensions (a*2,b*2,c*2) whereas a,b,c are different numbers.
I want to add them in a single csv file but it is getting over-write every time.
I used this 
[pandas DataFrame output end of csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134942/pandas-dataframe-output-end-of-csv)

but unable to do it.

My code-

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3]
for ii list_df:
   with open("cumulative_score.csv",'a',encoding='utf-8') as r:
       ii.to_csv(r)
```

But ,the final output ,I am getting is the last dataframe only instead of all the other dataframes.

Comment: you seem to have missed header=False

Comment: I want them under same sheet

Comment: Related, but not exactly a duplicate (since it doesn't answer why this doesn't work: it only answers how to get it working instead): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file (or, indeed, your own linked question).

Comment: @dartdog That is intentional, my files don't have header columns otherwise ,I'll be ignoring data points only

Comment: The lack of header may be the issue with mode='a' and header false, shouldn't be since that only affects how 1st row handled

Comment: Can you append normally to a file? So use `r.write("something")` instead of `ii.to_csv(r)` in your code, and see if you get three lines with "something".

Comment: @9769953 even when I am not using a loop and writing dataframes line by line, it doesn't work

Comment: That wasn't my question: can you append normal text to a standard (text) file?

Comment: @9769953 Let me check

Comment: @dartdog it doesn't work even after header=false

Comment: @9769953 Yes, it is appending but in same line

Comment: The same line part is understandable: there is no newline in that string. At least it's not something in your OS / filesystem that is preventing files from being appended. It could be a bug in Pandas to_csv method then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_csv()` method has a mode option; try using that instead:

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in list_df:
   df.to_csv("cumulative_score.csv", mode='a')
```

Comment: Interestingly, this solution works for me, but using the `with open(...` solution as in your code, does not work for me.

Comment: My bad ,I mistook this as with open function ,this works but `with open (` way doesn't .Any idea ,why it doesn't?

Comment: @Mark ... try nesting `for` loop INSIDE `with()`.